# Create branch and push it git alias

Tags: git, alias, zsh

How do I make an alias that creates a local branch and pushes it upstream? I've tried

```
publish = !git checkout -b $1 && git push -u origin $1
```

I get

```
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch/test'
error: dst ref refs/heads/mybranch/test receives from more      than one src.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://myurl'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final command turns out to be `git checkout -b mybranch/test && git push -u origin mybranch/test mybranch/test` as `$1` is substituted with the first parameter and the parameter is also added to the end of your command. Either leave out your last `$1`, so that you have

```
publish = !git checkout -b $1 && git push -u origin
```

or wrap your commandchain in a function like

```
publish = !publish_new_branch() { [ $# -ne 1 ] && echo 'error: publish needs exactly one argument' >&2 && exit 1; git checkout -b \"$1\" && git push -u origin \"$1\"; }; publish_new_branch
```

I usually prefer the latter option as it is more clear what happens.

Comment: First worked, the other didn't work. publish_new_branch() { [ $: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file. Thanks!

Comment: @uraza the second was how you give it to the `git config` command, not how it is contained in the config file. But as the syntax suggests it is the line from the config file, I updated my answer. You have to escape the double-quotes if you are editing the file directly instead of with git commands.

Answer (score 0):

I use this because I frequently work with remotes. First argument is the remote; second is your branch name. "nb" is for "new branch".

```
# ~/.gitconfig

[alias]
  nb = "!sh -c \"git checkout -b $2; git push -u $1 $2\" -"
```

usage:

```
git nb origin my-new-branch
```